# WPF Binding source is not DataContext as expected

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a simple binding question as I feel I'm missing something fundamental in my view of how binding works.

I assume that since I've set the DataContext of my MainWindow to a ViewModel in code-behind, that all of the binding in MainWindow.xaml would assume source of this DataContext unless otherwise specified.  This does not seem to be the case when I'm using my UserControl (which itself has a ViewModel driving it)

My scenario is best described in code:

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private ViewModels.MainMenuViewModel vm;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    vm = new ViewModels.MainMenuViewModel();
    this.DataContext = vm;
}
```

MainWindow.xaml (using the data-context set in code-behind)

```
x:Class="Mediafour.Machine.EditorWPF.Views.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Machine.EditorWPF.Views"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Machine.EditorWPF"
xmlns:localVM="clr-namespace:Machine.EditorWPF.ViewModels"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="650">



  <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <uc:MachineTreeView x:Name="MachineTreeView" Grid.Column="0" MachineDocument="{Binding Path=CurrentDocument}" />
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
       public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            OpenMachine(@"D:\Projects\Agnes\EditorWPF\Test.machine");
        }

        private void OpenMachine(string filePath)
        {
            MachineDocument currentDocument = MachineDocument.OpenFile(filePath);
            CurrentDocument = currentDocument;
        }

        private MachineDocument _currentDocument;
        public MachineDocument CurrentDocument
        {
            get { return _currentDocument; }
            set
            {
                if (_currentDocument != null)
                {
                    _currentDocument.Dispose();
                    _currentDocument = null;
                }

                _currentDocument = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentDocument"); //this fires
            }
        }
```

Using this approach, the binding statement in MainWindow.xaml errors out.  Looking at Snoop binding error, it states that the **CurrentDocument** property is not found in **MachineViewModel**

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'CurrentDocument' property not found on 'object' ''MachineViewModel' (HashCode=27598891)'. BindingExpression:Path=CurrentDocument; DataItem='MachineViewModel' (HashCode=27598891); target element is 'MachineTreeView' (Name='MachineTreeView'); target property is 'MachineDocument' (type 'MachineDocument')
```

Why is it looking at the **MachineViewModel** when the binding is done in **MainWindow**?

Other binding properties in MainWindow do work as expected, this is the only UserControl binding I have though.

Comment: sounds like your uc is over-riding the DC. Post the UC code where you assign the DC.

Comment: You were correct LL. I was over-riding the DC in the UC.  I'm now setting the DC of the root-element of UC instead.  It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either it is a simple mistake

- you're setting `MainMenuViewModel` instead of `MainWindowViewModel` as `MainWindow.DataContext`

or maybe

- you set the `DataContext` for the UserControl in the wrong manner. Take a look at this [Simple Pattern for Creating Re-useable UserControls](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/) to do it the right way.

Comment: This is almost 100% a mistake of the wrong model being bound to the Window's DataContext based on the OP's posted code, re: `MainMenuViewModel` vs. `MainWindowViewModel`. Good catch.

Comment: Thanks LPL, you were right about the simple mistake you pointed out above (unfortunately that was result of careless copy/paste work when submitting the question)...

Comment: The Real Help was the link to Pattern for Creating Re-usable UC. I was setting the UserControl's DataContext to the ViewModel for that UC.  I have now changed that to set the DataContext of the root element of the UC and all works splendidly! Thanks for your help.